# Load Image VB.NET from SQL Server 2005 type Image

Tags: sql, vb.net, image, sql-server-2005

I have problem with load image in VB.NET 2005 from SQL SERVER 2005 type image.
SQL table "pegawai"

```
code  varchar(15)
foto  image
```

VB Code:

```
Sub SendQueryParam(ByVal ssql As String, ByVal ParamArray args() As Object)
    On Error GoTo errSendQuery

    sqlnote = True
    mCMD.CommandText = ssql
    For i = LBound(args) To UBound(args) Step 2
        mCMD.Parameters.Item((i - LBound(args)) \ 2).Type = args(i)
        mCMD.Parameters.Item((i - LBound(args)) \ 2).Size = 500
        mCMD.Parameters.Item((i - LBound(args)) \ 2).Value = args(i + 1)
    Next
    mCMD.Execute()
    Exit Sub
    errSendQuery:
    MsgBox("Send Query:" & Err.Description, , "Send Query Param")
    sqlnote = False
End Sub

Sub Get_Recordset(ByRef mREC As ADODB.Recordset)
    On Error Resume Next
    If mREC.State = 1 Then mREC.Close()
    mREC.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset
    mREC.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic
    mREC.Source = mCMD
    mREC.Open()
End Sub

Dim mEdit As New ADODB.Recordset
SendQueryParam("select * from pegawai where code='KR-00001.04.16'")
Get_Recordset(mEdit)
If Not mEdit.EOF Then
     Dim photo() As Byte = CType(mEdit("foto").Value, Byte())
     Dim ms As New MemoryStream(photo)
     myimage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
End If
```

myimage is pictureBox as component in VB.NET 
I got error "Parameter is not valid." in line "myimage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)" 
Thanks for your concern and GBU

Comment: you can read this article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437937/Save-and-Retrieve-Image-from-a-SQL-Server-Database

Comment: thanks for references i ll try